# withRegion(Regions) of AmazonS3ClientBuilder takes what parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

withRegion(Regions) of AmazonS3ClientBuilder takes what parameter? From AWS documentation says "It sets the region to be used by the client."

1. Is it the region where our application is running? So that there would be minimum latency as it will read from the same region of S3 bucket where the calling client is deployed?
2. Or it is the Region where S3 bucket is present?

Sample code of line:

AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

Please don't do any guess work.. An URL(pref doc.aws.amazon.com) to support your explanation will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

> Some services, such as IAM, do not support regions; therefore, their endpoints do not include a region. Some services, such as Amazon EC2, let you specify an endpoint that does not include a specific region, for example, https://ec2.amazonaws.com. In that case, AWS routes the endpoint to us-east-1.
>
> If a service supports regions, the resources in each region are independent. For example, if you create an Amazon EC2 instance or an Amazon SQS queue in one region, the instance or queue is independent from instances or queues in another region.

In this case, S3 buckets can be created in specific regions and there are multiple REST endpoints you can access. In the case of S3, you must connect to the same region as the bucket (except for calls such as `ListAllMyBuckets` that are region agnostic). For other services you do not.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

As you point out, the Javadoc for `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` is incredibly vague, because it inherits the `withBuilder` documentation from `AwsClientBuilder`, which is inherited by services that support regions and those that do not.

To further add to the confusion, particularly when reading older advice scattered over the internet, it was possible in the past to access any bucket from the *same* region with the S3 Java API (these calls may be slower).  It is possible to revert to this behaviour with `withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Builder.html#withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled-java.lang.Boolean-

> Configure whether global bucket access is enabled for clients generated by this builder.
>
> When global bucket access is enabled, the region to which a request is routed may differ from the region that is configured in `AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(String)` in order to make the request succeed.
>
> The following behavior is currently used when this mode is enabled:
>
> All requests that do not act on an existing bucket (for example, `AmazonS3Client.createBucket(String)`) will be routed to the region configured by `AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(String)`, unless the region is manually overridden with `CreateBucketRequest.setRegion(String)`, in which case the request will be routed to the region configured in the request.
>
> The first time a request is made that references an existing bucket (for example, `AmazonS3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest)`) a request will be made to the region configured by `AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(String)` to determine the region in which the bucket was created. This location may be cached in the client for subsequent requests acting on that same bucket.
>
> Enabling this mode has several drawbacks, because it has the potential to increase latency in the event that the location of the bucket is physically far from the location from which the request was invoked. For this reason, it is strongly advised when possible to know the location of your buckets and create a region-specific client to access that bucket.

Comment: I've already read this . but nothing is clearly written there .. It says "both the service endpoint [S3 bucket ..?] and signing region [where our app is deployed..?]" If the S3 bucket is in different region then??

Comment: There, dug around and found some hopefully better documentation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Further clarification post coffee.

Comment: `you must connect to the same region as the bucket` this means I should provide the region in withRegion(...) same as where the bucket is available, else the call will fail? Now another question arises, that as per Amazon, S3 bucket is available in all the regions. It will replicated in all other region (i think in 4 hours).. So for Read we can connect to any region, but for write we need to connect to the Region same as where the bucket was created..?

Comment: Also, `withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)` will actually ensure that call (Read/Write) will not fail. If the bucket is not in the same region as that provided in the withRegion(Regions.XXX), then it will look in another regions and cache that location. From next time onwards, it will look for the cached region, not the provided one. So, the latency added will be in the first call only, npt in the afterwards calls.

Comment: Regarding connecting to the same region- that's correct.  You can also change the region dynamically with `setRegion`. This is important when referencing and connecting to buckets.  Regarding your second question, yes, that's exactly right too. If your client lives for a long time, the caching should help out well there.

Comment: Unfortunately, Instance created by AmazonS3ClientBuilder is immutable. Hence we cannot set the region or any other property once the object is created. I've tried this :'(

Comment: Ah, I misread that- yeah. The setRegion only works with the builder. :/

Comment: *"Now another question arises, that as per Amazon, S3 bucket is available in all the regions. It will replicated in all other region (i think in 4 hours).. So for Read we can connect to any region, but for write we need to connect to the Region same as where the bucket was created..?"*  I'm not sure where you're getting any of this.  Buckets exist in exactly one region.  Replication copies objects to a second bucket, with a different name, in a second region, in near real time... but you must access that second bucket explicitly by name if you want to read the replica.